# C++ templates - generalize scalar product for double and complex<double> vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector, double, complex-numbers

I am trying to overload the `*` operator for computing the scalar product for both `vector<double>` and `vector<complex<double>>` vectors using templates, and I arrived to this after trying everything I know:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> T operator* (const vector<T> &a, const vector<T> &b) {
    T retvar; complex<double> c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) c += conj(a[i])*b[i];
    if (is_same<T, double>::value) retvar = c.real();
    else                           retvar = c;  // (*) the error is generated by this line
    return retvar;
}

int main() {
    vector<double> a, b;
    a.push_back(5); b.push_back(3);
    cout << a*b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is: I compute the scalar product as for complex numbers, and then I return it contained in a variable which type is given by the template, to avoid any weird casting. However, g++ throws the following error at line (*):

```
error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'complex<double>'
```

I honestly ran out of ideas, what would be a good way to get out of this *without overloading the operator twice*?

Comment: I believe using `auto` and/or trailing return type is what you should be investigating.

Comment: isnt the scalar product the same for doubles and complex? I mean apart from one being double the other complex?

Comment: Don't overload operations for types you don't own.  If you want to , wrap the vectors in your own classes and provide overloads for them.

Comment: Agree with @NathanOliver. Use an explicitly named function - `scalar_product`.

Comment: Also, the math doesn't look right to me. For `vector<double>`, I can imagine using `sum(a[i]*b[i]), for i = 0, N-1`. What formula would you use for `vector<complex<double>>`?

Comment: So, for complex vectors one needs to compute the complex conjugate of every member of one of the two vectors, say `sum(conj(a[i])*b[i])`, and would like to do it overloading and operator for the sake of learning, although I understand that a proper function would be more appropriate.

Comment: Are you using c++17? Then use `if constexpr (is_same...)`.

Comment: @super that is exactly what I was looking for! It totally worked, and honestly I don't know how. I never saw before the `constexpr` keyword. So basically it computes at compile time the content of the brackets so that the compiler just pins down the outcome of the `if .. then .. `? What if it depends on a user input of some kind?

Comment: @marco Yes, the compiler chooses which branch is used at compile-time, so it only works with compile-time values.

Answer (score 0):

Dont overload operators of types you dont own. Instead you can write a

```
template <typename T>
struct my_vect {
    std::vector<T> data;
    T operator* (const my_vect<T>& other);
};
```

Next, `std::conj` returns a complex number, no matter what was the type of the argument. In my opinion this is unfortunate, because in maths there is no difference between the scalar product of complex vectors and non-complex vectors. The conjugate of a real number is a real number. To restore that nice property one can use a `my_conj`:

```
template <typename T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> :std::true_type {};


template <typename T>
T my_conj(const T&t) {
    if constexpr (is_complex<T>::value) return std::conj(t);
    else return t;
}
```

Now the definition of the scalar product can be the same for complex and non complex vectors. Complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> :std::true_type {};


template <typename T>
T my_conj(const T&t) {
    if constexpr (is_complex<T>::value) return std::conj(t);
    else return t;
}


template <typename T>
struct my_vect {
    std::vector<T> data;
    T operator* (const my_vect<T>& other) {
        T result;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) result += my_conj(data[i])*other.data[i];
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
   my_vect<double> x{{1,2,3}};
   std::cout << x*x << '\n';
   my_vect<std::complex<double>> y{{ {1,2} }};
   std::cout << y*y;
}
```

PS: You should check that the two vectors are of same size.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it will work, but someone already left a comment that actually solved everything, just few moments before your answer ..

Comment: @marco i saw the comment, but `is_same` alone will only let you check for `double`, while checking for specializations of `complex` works for anything that is complex or not